# Вызов setState блокирует событие дочернего элемента

Tags: reactjs

Есть форма такого вида:

```
<ContentBlock>
  <ReactTable />
</ContentBlock>
```

У ContentBlock есть свой обработчик событий:

```
handleClick {
  this.setState({...})
}
```

У ReactTable есть свой дефолтный хендлер на клик по колонке - сортировка.

Проблема: Если я использую this.setState в обработчике ContentBlock, то каким-то чудом блокируется событие ReactTable. Клик по колонке ничего не дает. Если попробовать заменить this.setState, допустим, на вывод чего-либо в консоль, то все работает.

Comment: Что должно произойти при клике на `ContentBlock` в обработчике `handleClick`? Какой-то странный `handleClick` у вас в примере, может быть он должен быть функцией:  `handleClick(e) {...}`?

Comment: По клику на ContentBlock должен скрываться попап. Попап смотрит стейт всего класса, а хэндлер его меняет.
Полный код: 
 `hidePopup = () => {
this.setState({
        PingPopup: {
          ...this.state.PingPopup,
          show: false,
        },
      });
}`

Comment: для того, чтобы скрывать попапы , модалки и пр. по клику вне, лучше бы использовать hoc вроде `withOutsideEvent` и вызывать onClose колбэк в таком случае. Таким образом логика не размазывается по разным местам

Comment: Попап у меня вызывается кнопкой, закрывается кликом по любому месту, кроме самого попапа. Где у меня размазана логика? И колбэк на закрытие мне совершенно не нужен. 
За наводку на hoc большое спасибо.